# Assigning function results to variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I’m learning JavaScript, and want to understand this behavior.

I was studying the following code:

```js
function multiNum(x,y){
  return x*y
}
var num = multiNum(3,4);
document.write(num)
```

I tried to type this myself, and this is what I came up with:

```js
function multiNum(x,y){
  return x*y
}
document.write(multiNum(3,4))
```

I thought I could put `multiNum(3,4)` into the `document.write()` instead of making another variable.

So, is it just a rule that I have to create another variable and put the new one into `document.write()`?

Comment: You are not forced to create a variable. It's just easier to read most of the time, when variable names make sense, and to avoid having cluttered code. Here, your example is simple. But imagine having something  like `a(b(c(42, c('x'))))`.  This is harder to read _(which closing parenthesis corresponds to the opening one?)_, and decomposing that into well-named variables will make everything much easier to maintain.

Comment: So that is eventually for making code easier to read and understand! Thank you !!

Comment: Also, sometimes you need to use the result of a function multiple times. It's usually better to save it in a variable than call the function repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Both your examples are correct and will produce the same result. It's just a matter of style.

If you want your code to be easier to read, then seperating it out like in your first example is best.

If you want your code to be a smaller in size. Then the second example is best.

Seperating things out is best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to create an extra variable, but a lot of the times it makes the code just easier to read and understand. They say your variable names should generally describe its contents, this way everyone, including someone else who does not know the code, can have a basic understanding of what is going on.

In your example, it is not very much needed to create an extra variable since it's a very simple code snippet. I like to create them anyway, just to stay in the rythm of doing so. But it is your choice.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question and the in order to fully understand it would be beneficial to look into [javascript expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators). Basically an assignment in javascript looks looks like

```
variable_name = expression
```

when you create that `variable` the `expression` is evaluated

```
//so this
number = 3 * 5
//is the same as
number = 15
```

`Functions` can be called with an expression, literal (like a `string` or `int`), or a variable name

```
// '|' means 'or'
function(expression | literal | variable)
```

if you pass an expression to a function `function(expression)`, that `expression`is first evaluated and then passed into the function.

```
// so
function(3*5)
//is the same as
function(15)
```

And the same thing goes for function calls. If a function is called inside another function, it is first evaluated and it's result is the outer functions argument.

Lets look at this example

```
function increment(number){
 return number + 1
}
n = 1
document.write(increment(n))
```

First `document.write` is called with the parameter `increment(n)`
and `n = 1`

```
//so 
increment(n) = increment(1) = 2
//following me? now we can see that
document.write(increment(n)) 
//is the same as
document.write(2)
//!!
```

I hope that helps!

edit:

to bring it back to your example

```
function multiNum(x,y){
  return x*y
}
var num = multiNum(3,4) // num = 12
//so
document.write(num)
//is the same as
document.write(12)
```

Comment: Nice job recognizing the fundamental technical question and walking through the logic as the interpreter sees it, instead of simply validating that it’s correct. This should be useful for future readers in helping them understand how the JavaScript interpreter parses expressions.

Answer (score 0):

What you did with the second solution is pretty efficient.

Generally, the first approach is useful only if you would want the computed value of `multiNum(3,4)` to be used later in your script. And that's why you would store it in a separate variable so that you don't have to compute the value again.

If you are sure that you won't need it again then what you did later as `document.write(multiNum(3,4))` is the best way to go.